# Clicking on a button with Selenium using Xpath or CSS Selector

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I've spent a couple of hours trying to click on a button using various selectors before asking a question here, but nothing seems to work

```
WebElement add= driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("+"));
WebElement add= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='button']"));
WebElement confirm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'IconButton-h85035-0 indexstyles__PlusButton')]"));
```

No available examples have a similar html layout as the page I'm working with.
I am not sure how to create the xPath to the button.
I would appreciate any hints on how to create xPath, or the CSS selector, no ready solution is expected, but any help to understand how to refere to that particular element.

That is the code of the plus button:

```
<button data-testid="tselectionSpinbuttonPlus" type="button" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" width="44px" height="44px" class="IconButton-h85035-0 indexstyles__PlusButton-sc-108enfc-3 bAZDfp">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="1.5em" height="1.5em" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="BaseSvg-sc-9y47q5-0 PlusIcon___StyledBaseSvg-sc-11rza9m-0 VCaQT">
      <path d="M13 11V3h-2v8H3v2h8v8h2v-8h8v-2h-8z">
      </path>
    </svg>
 </button>
```

[image]

Comment: try this `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-testid='tselectionSpinbuttonPlus']")).click()`

Answer (score 1):

To locate/click on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-testid='tselectionSpinbuttonPlus']")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='tselectionSpinbuttonPlus']")).click();
  ```

---

Ideally to locate/click on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[data-testid='tselectionSpinbuttonPlus']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='tselectionSpinbuttonPlus']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try with below:
[Code snipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7K49.png)

```
WebElement add= driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("+"));
        Actions ac1 = new Actions(driver);
                    ac.clickAndHold(add).build().perform();
```